# How to fix the Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget in a simple code

Tags: flutter

I try to solve Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget

[image]

Exception caught by widgets library:

> Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:user_profile_example/data.dart';
    
    import 'package:user_profile_example/widget/cookbook_item.dart';
    
    class bookmarked_recipes extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Column(children: [
            // Design a clickable container which has a row of icon and text.
            InkWell(
              child: Align(
                // Align them on the left of the screen.
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Icon(Icons.add),
                        Text("Add new cookbook", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                      ],
                    )),
              ),
              onTap: () {},
            ),
            // make the rest of the screen for the gridview items.
            Expanded(
              child: GridView.count(
                crossAxisCount: 2, // 2 items in each row
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
                // map all available cookbooks and list them in Gridviwe.
                children: Cookbook_Data.map((c) => cookbook_item(
                      key,
                      c.id,
                      c.cookbookName,
                      c.imageURLCookbook,
                    )).toList(),
              ),
            ),
          ]),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. try to Just remove your `Expanded` Widget
change my children to your children , refer `GridView.count()` [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/grid-lists)

```
    Column(
        children: [
          InkWell(
            child: Align(
              // Align them on the left of the screen.
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Icon(Icons.add),
                    Text(
                      "Add new cookbook",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            onTap: () {},
          ),
          // make the rest of the sceen for the gridview items.
          GridView.count(
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            crossAxisCount: 2, // 2 items in each row
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
            // map all available cookbooks and list them in Gridviwe.
            children: List.generate(
              10,
              (index) {
                return Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Item $index',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5,
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
         ],
       ),
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Comment: where should i put this part  child: GridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: 2, // 2 items in each row
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
            // map all available cookbooks and list them in Gridviwe.
            children: Cookbook_Data.map((c) => cookbook_item(
                  key,
                  c.id,
                  c.cookbookName,
                  c.imageURLCookbook,
                )).toList(),
          ),
        ),

Comment: just remove my `gridview.count()` and add your `GridView.count( crossAxisCount: 2, // 2 items in each row padding: EdgeInsets.all(25), // map all available cookbooks and list them in Gridviwe. children: Cookbook_Data.map((c) => cookbook_item( key, c.id, c.cookbookName, c.imageURLCookbook, )).toList(), ), )`

Comment: what does that mean ? flutter indicate in viewport.dart --> if (!constraints.hasBoundedHeight) {
              throw FlutterError.fromParts(<DiagnosticsNode>[

Comment: this consist of minimum and maximum widths and heights. refer [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/box-constraints)

Answer (score 0):

`GridView` will take up all the space there is just like what an `Expanded` widget does. So, the `Expanded` is redundant and also the reason for "Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget". So try removing the `Expanded` widget.

Answer (score 0):

Ok
This is the class of cook_book_item
I don't understand where is the problem
I should fix the error as soon as posible

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class cookbook_item extends StatelessWidget {
  final String id;
  final String cookbookName;
  final String imageURLCookbook;
  // final VoidCallback onClicked;

  const cookbook_item(
    Key? key,
    this.id,
    this.cookbookName,
    this.imageURLCookbook,
  );

  void selectCookbook() {}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final String image = imageURLCookbook;
// this section will return one item of Grid Items that in bookmarked recipes page.
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              child: Image.network(imageURLCookbook),
            ),
          ),
          Container(

              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
              color: Color(0xff9C635614),
              child: Text(cookbookName,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.white)),
            ),

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```